# Google+ interactive post - What mechanism are the they using?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-plus

I would like to post to Google+ throught their [interactive post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) feature. How does the authentication works once you allowed the app to post to your timeline? They don't need an access token - are they setting a cookie instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might misunderstand how the interactive post publishes to the stream. The posting is entirely controlled by the user, it is not done programmatically via a REST API. The interactive post button does require a signed in user so you can also get an OAuth token back, but that is independent of the posting by the user.